# Hama KVM Switch only working with one of two connected devices

Tags: windows-10, kvm-switch

I recently bought a HAMA KVM Switch. Specifically it is the HAMA 00200135. I have a Lenovo ThinkPad X1 Carbon and my desktop pc connected to the switch. The peripherals which are connected to the switch are:

a Razer Viper Ultimate (Mouse), a Steelseries Arctis 7 (Headset) and a Razer BlackWidow (Keyboard). Furthermore I have two 27" AOC monitors which are directly connected to both the laptop and the desktop pc.

The laptop is connected to a Dell Docking Station which is in turn connected to the switch. The laptop works like a charm with the KVM switch.

But the desktop pc disconnects and reconnects to all peripherals in an random interval which can be very frustrating. Both the pc and the docking station (laptop) are connected to the switch via a USB3.0 to VGA cable. Since the KVM has no power supply on its own i thought that the cause could be power. What I have tried to do is disconnect the Docking Station from the KVM Switch when using the pc. But the issue persisted so it has to do something with my PC alone. Unfortunately I can think of no good way to troubleshoot the issue.

So what is a good way to narrow down the problem? I'm also open for suggestions where I can get rid of the KVM.